# Does a HTTP response double as a TCP acknowledge signal?

Tags: networking, tcp

I understand that TCP is considered a reliable protocol because it sends an acknowledge signal to the transmitter, allowing it to know that the packet arrived intact at destination.

When dealing with an incoming HTTP request, does TCP send an acknowledge signal before passing the data to the HTTP protocol for processing? Or does the response message sent from the HTTP protocol double as the acknowledge signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems somewhat off-topic here. But...

Short answer is yes. TCP sends an ACK before HTTP sees the data. But an HTTP response is NOT a TCP ACK.

A slightly longer answer is that TCP acks are independent of processing at higher layers in the stack on most systems. An ACK is usually sent for each window of data. The window is the amount of data both ends agree to send without requiring an ack - a circular description, but the reality is *way* beyond the scope of an answer here, the point is that it is beyond the scope of an answer here to fully describe the behaviour.

A longer answer is that HTTP (at least in versions 1.0 and 1.1) is a message passing protocol implemented on top of a stream protocol (TCP) implemented on top of a packet based network (TCP/IP). HTTP (1.x) is not party to what is happening at lowers layers in the stack. Although TCP/IP was designed way before the OSI network model came along, most implementations follow the model (although TCP/IP only spans layers 3 and 4).

The next version of the truth is that the application layer (in this case HTTP) can ask the TCP layer to push the data out across the network without delay (see RFC793 Section 2.8) - and will typically do this for the last packet of an HTTP request.

However with HTTP/2.0 its a completely different story; there are additional network protocol layers on top of the stream exposed by TCP/IP implementing stream multiplexing.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP uses TCP as the underlying protocol. ACK's can be send in empty packets (no application data) but also in packets containing application data. Thus the TCP ACK for the client request could be a separate packet without data or it could be send in the same packet as the HTTP response.